# "Make" fails with Clang error - how do I get the error from Clang?

Tags: c++, makefile, clang, linker-errors, glew

Main question is: How do I get the clang error out of make?

I have been trying to follow [these instructions](https://riptutorial.com/opengl/example/21105/setup-modern-opengl-4-1-on-macos--xcode--glfw-and-glew-) to install GLEW. On second look I've seen that GLEW might not really be necessary on Mac OS X, but I'd still like to find out how to get the error from the problem I was having. (I am not very experienced with make and could not make any similar online solutions work).

Theoretically I should download GLEW, unzip, and run 'make' in the file. This is the output of make:

```sh
$ make
cc -dynamiclib -install_name /usr/local/lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib -current_version 2.1.0 -compatibility_version 2.1 -o lib/libGLEW2.1.0.dylib tmp/darwin/default/shared/glew.o -framework OpenGL
ld: malformed file
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGLframework/OpenGL.tbd:4:18: error: unknown enumerated scalar
platform:    zippered
             ^~~~~~~~
 file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Framework//OpenGL.framework/OpenGL.tbd'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib] Error 1
```

Make -n shows that this is just the first command and it pretty much immediately fails. I have tried `make V=1`, `make VERBOSE=1`, and `make SHELL='sh -x'`, but they don't give me additional detail about the clang error. I've also tried running the cc command with -v:

```sh
$ cc -v -dynamiclib -install_name /usr/local/lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib -current_version 2.1.0 -compatibility_version 2.1 -o lib/libGLEW2.1.0.dylib tmp/darwin/default/shared/glew.o -framework OpenGL
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
"Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -dylib -dylib_compatibility_version 2.1 -dylib_current_version 2.1.0 -arch x86_64 -dyib_install_name /usr/local/lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib -macosx_version_min 10.14.0 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -o lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib tmp/darwin/default/shared/glew.o -framework OpenGL -L/usr/local/lib -lSystem / Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchains/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: malformed file
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGLframework/OpenGL.tbd:4:18: error: unknown enumerated scalar
platform:    zippered
             ^~~~~~~~
 file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Framework//OpenGL.framework/OpenGL.tbd'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib] Error 1
```

I don't think I am actually managing to get the real error out of clang. So how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is

```
Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -dynamic -dylib -dylib_compatibility_version 2.1 -dylib_current_version 2.1.0 -arch x86_64 -dyib_install_name /usr/local/lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib -macosx_version_min 10.14.0 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -o lib/libGLEW.2.1.0.dylib tmp/darwin/default/shared/glew.o -framework OpenGL -L/usr/local/lib -lSystem / Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchains/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

command that fails, which is `ld`, not `clang`. You can run this command separately to get the same error message.

And

```
ld: malformed file
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGLframework/OpenGL.tbd:4:18: error: unknown enumerated scalar
platform:    zippered
             ^~~~~~~~
file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Framework//OpenGL.framework/OpenGL.tbd'
```

is linker's error message. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with compilation process on Mac, so can't advice how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks anyway, it's still useful for me to know it's not clang :)